# How to rotate the screen to landscape (or portrait) by programmable way?

Tags: android

How to rotate the screen to landscape (or portrait) by programmable way?
I am trying to make it independent when user rotates the screen.

Is it possible thing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with the sample below...

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // You can set the value initially by
    // ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED. Once set it
    // retains it's value. The View will be rendered in the specified
    // orientation using the code below.
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
Activity.setRequestedOrientation()
```

with these parameters:

```
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) for further reference

Comment: How do you rotate the screen in Emulator?

Comment: Home and PageUp on the numpad, but make sure you take numlock off first.