# Disable Rotation

Tags: android, web, autorotate

I have an a web app using PhoneGap, and I'd like the app to only work in a portrait mode. Where is the bit of documentation I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong forum for this type of question... but I think it's answered in this question over at [StackOverFlow.com](http://stackoverflow.com):

[How to rotate the screen to landscape (or portrait) by programmable way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532058/how-to-rotate-the-screen-to-landscape-or-portrait-by-programmable-way)